How to make '.zshrc' to search for sourced files in the specific folder and not in the folder from which the terminal has been opened
macOS 14.5, Zsh 5.9.
ls -A -- ~/:
.zshrc
system-wide-clipboard.zsh

cat -- ~/.zshrc:
autoload -Uz zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zmv -L'

. ./system-wide-clipboard.zsh

If I open the Terminal application in, for example, ~/test/, Zsh is trying to find system-wide-clipboard.zsh in ~/test/ and not in ~/.
How to fix this?
(What I have tried myself is to replace . ./system-wide-clipboard.zsh with . system-wide-clipboard.zsh, source ./system-wide-clipboard.zsh, or source system-wide-clipboard.zsh, but this didn't help.)

Give an absolute path to the file:
. ~/system-wide-clipboard.zsh


Thanks. It seems I really do need to take a weekend.
